# How to produce a frequency dataframe using 3 columns?

Tags: r

From a dataframe of 3 columns

```
df <- data.frame(month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), country = c("US", "US", "US", "Brazil", "US", "Brazil", "UK", "UK", "Brazil", "US"), id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

I would like to count the id for every country for every month. How is it possible to take the result of table() with more than one columns?

Here an example output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(month=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), country = c("US", "Brazil", "UK","US", "Brazil", "UK","US", "Brazil", "UK","US", "Brazil", "UK"), frequency = c(3,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,1,1,0))
> df2
   month country frequency
1      1      US         3
2      1  Brazil         0
3      1      UK         0
4      2      US         1
5      2  Brazil         2
6      2      UK         0
7      3      US         0
8      3  Brazil         0
9      3      UK         2
10     4      US         1
11     4  Brazil         1
12     4      UK         0
```

Comment: Try `out <- as.data.frame(table(df[, c("month", "country")])); out[order(out$month), ]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way with `dplyr` and `tidyr::complete()` -

```
df %>% 
  count(month, country) %>% 
  complete(month, country, fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   month country     n
   <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
 1     1 Brazil      0
 2     1 UK          0
 3     1 US          3
 4     2 Brazil      2
 5     2 UK          0
 6     2 US          1
 7     3 Brazil      0
 8     3 UK          2
 9     3 US          0
10     4 Brazil      1
11     4 UK          0
12     4 US          1
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, whenever I think about frequency tables with more than one column (`table(...)`), I think of `xtabs(~each + and + every + column, data=myframe)`. That's not to say that `table` doesn't support multiple columns ... it does, but I find the `formula` interface a little more intuitive to me.

`xtabs` returns 3D tables as well(see `xtabs(~cyl+vs+am,data=mtcars)`), and as you can tell, it can easily be converted into a "long"-style frame (which it has in common with `table`). (In fact, the output from `xtabs` includes the class `"table"`, so anything that works on the latter should work on `xtabs`. *shrug*)

```r
as.data.frame(xtabs(~ month + country, data = df))
#    month country Freq
# 1      1  Brazil    0
# 2      2  Brazil    2
# 3      3  Brazil    0
# 4      4  Brazil    1
# 5      1      UK    0
# 6      2      UK    0
# 7      3      UK    2
# 8      4      UK    0
# 9      1      US    3
# 10     2      US    1
# 11     3      US    0
# 12     4      US    1
```